# Reviewing Proposed Edits

Tags: discussion, editing

I just tried to edit someone's question, and was told that there was already another edit on hold, and that I'd have to wait till that one was reviewed.  How do we get the privilege to review proposed edits?

Answer (score 5):

There's a [full list of privileges](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and at what reputation you earn them in the Help Center.

When you earn the privilege [to edit questions and answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) without peer review, you also earn the privilege to review suggested edits.